# How to reinitialize windows scroll in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have execute function on windows scroll that is working but when i changed the content of particular element then that is not working please help..

```
$(window).paged_scroll({
    handleScroll:function (page,container,doneCallback) {
        getProducts();
        return true;
    },
    triggerFromBottom:'100',
    targetElement : $('.shop-product-list')
});
```

Comment: Explain changed the content of particular element, also make a jsfiddle

Comment: Take a look here, this post will be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/575194/jQuery-paged-scroll-Facebook-like-infinite-scroll

Comment: I am creating li in ul by calling this getProducts() function first time on document.ready event after that on paged_scroll again calling this getProducts() function and prepend the li in ul that is working but i am click on particular a tag and changed the html of ul after that when i am scrolling then paged_scroll in not working.

Comment: Hi Rex are you there ?

Comment: what happened, still any issue?

Comment: Yes paged_scroll event is not occurred.